# How can you call commands in django project?

Tags: python, django, cmd, command

I want to run a command on a django project but don't know how to call it from cmd

I have a class Command(BaseCommand) and a handle method inside my class
the python file name is assign_tasks.py. How to call this command on cmd

Comment: What's wrong with doc ? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/custom-management-commands/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you've put the file where your command is in the `management/commands` folder, you should be able to go:

```
python3 manage.py assign_tasks
```